# Deluge WebUI and download path

Tags: deluge

I installed Deluge and the webui.

I set the download path in the GUI client on the server, however when I launch the WebUI and click on preferences, the `Download To` folder shows `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Downloads` which is not what it's set on the main client.

Is this value used? or Incorrect?

Do I need to manually put in the path on the server as if I was on the physical server to where I want them downloaded to?

Answer (score 1):

The `download To` setting is used when torrents are initially added, it must be manually entered and there should be enough space in that location.

Eg. `/var/lib/deluge/Downloads`

If you would like to change this location after the torrent has been added you need to **right click** the torrent and say **Move Storage**. Then manually type the path on the server.

**Side Note**

I would recommend removing the main deluge client, it is not a requirement and is just a native desktop app for deluge.

```
sudo apt-get remove deluge
```

The minimum required is the `deluged` and `deluge-webui`.